# PostgreSQL userinput substract in Java

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to take the user input, and then substract it from one of the rows in the `amount column` in the table `BOX`. As you can see in the code example below, I have programmed it with the `scanner class` so if the user types the number 2, it will substract 2 from the `RED_BOX_LARGE` row in the `amount` column in the `BOX` table. The problem is, that I am going to add 300 more rows, and I cannot really do this kind of `if-statement` 300 times, there must be another way, isn't there a way to program it to just substract from the row with how much the userinput is, without already specifying the number. I am using Java with PostgreSQL.

```
if(userinput.equals("2")){
String one = "UPDATE BOX SET AMOUNT = 
(SELECT AMOUNT FROM BOX WHERE NAME = 'RED_BOX_LARGE') -2 WHERE NAME='RED_BOX_LARGE';";
stmt.executeUpdate(one);
}
```

This is the table.

```
      name       |  price  | form_factor | amount
-----------------+---------+-------------+--------
 RED_BOX_SMALL   | 17.1125 | RED_SMALL   |     10
 BLUE_BOX_LARGE  |  1586.5 | BLUE_LARGE  |     10
 BLUE_BOX_SMALL  |  1324.5 | BLUE_SMALL  |     10
 GREEN_BOX_LARGE | 1175.25 | GREEN_LARGE |     10
 GREEN_BOX_SMALL |   930.5 | GREEN_SMALL |     10
 GRAY_BOX_LARGE  |  735.25 | GRAY_LARGE  |     10
 GRAY_BOX_SMALL  |   450.5 | GRAY_SMALL  |     10
 RED_BOX_LARGE   | 2120.75 | RED_LARGE   |      3
(8 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, splitting a sql query String in multiple parts is not very advised as overusing it may be error prone but for isolated cases it may be acceptable.

So you could split your query string in two parts.

```
  String one = "UPDATE BOX SET AMOUNT = 
   (SELECT AMOUNT FROM BOX WHERE NAME =                        
  'RED_BOX_LARGE') - "
```

And

```
   String two = " WHERE NAME='RED_BOX_LARGE';";
```

After concatenate them by adding between them the user input.

```
   String query = one + userinput + two;
   stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

You could also templatize the user input in a single query String and use 
`public static String format(String format, Object... args)` to set the user input value.